# Raspberry Pi screensaver/DMPS on/off to trigger shell script on change

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, gpio, touchscreen, screensaver

I've got a touch screen without backlight control and and turning off the HDMI-output just brings up a "no signal" placeholder on the screen.

I've soldered a octocoupler to the power toggle to control it via the GPIO-pins and that works fine.

What I would like to do is to toggle a shell script (screen_toggle.sh) everytime the Pi changes DPMS state. I.e as soon as DMPS blanks the screen the screen_toggle.sh would be triggered, and as soon as mouse (touch) input is registered screen_toggle.sh would be triggered again to wake the screen.

Anyone with ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: You might want to try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks @SiKing, will post there too. Might fit here as well since polling screen state is universal I guess... DBUS or x set q.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here looking for a solution.

Got around to fix it by doing the following. screen_switch.sh calls the GPIO in the Pi in my case but could do what ever someone would want.

```
#!/bin/bash

idletime=60000 # in milliseconds
screen_toggle=1

while true; do
    idle=`xprintidle`
    #echo $idle >> /home/pi/idle.log
    if [ "$idle" -gt "$idletime" ] && [ "$screen_toggle" == 1 ]
    then
      screen_toggle=0
      source /home/pi/screen_switch.sh
      echo "Turned off" >> /home/pi/screen_check.log
    elif [ "$idle" -lt "$idletime" ] && [ "$screen_toggle" == 0 ]
      then
        screen_toggle=1
        source /home/pi/screen_switch.sh
        echo "Turned on" >> /home/pi/screen_check.log
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```